# Spring ROO Build Errors

Tags: spring-roo

When building Springroo project, I am getting GPG error.
I hope I need to have few certificates to run this. When i comment the sign-artifacts exceptions in pom file, Build gets success. But when I copy the modified jar like thyme-leaf, it shows some exception in loading this jar at the time of  running the Rooshell. Help is needed.

Comment: please add specific logs, so that someone can help you.

Comment: We cannot tell you how to fix (or avoid) the error if you didn't tell us what the error is.

Comment: The issue is when I copy the modified jars that are generated when spring roo project is built, I get some validation error when loading thyme leaf. And when building, I have commented out signing of jars. I hope this should be the issue. So i want to know what steps to be followed for the sign artifacts execution to work?

Comment: How do you build the Roo project? Also, why do you need to compile it by yourself and don't download the Spring Roo binary bundle available in http://projects.spring.io/spring-roo/ instead?